# The entity type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SomeModel]' provided for the argument 'clrType' must be a reference type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm getting the error message

> The entity type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SomeModel]' provided for the argument 'clrType' must be a reference type.

When I try to do `add-migration`. I have no idea what and where the problem is here.

I don't know what is wrong with the `UserRequest` class.

I saw some similar questions, but their problem was with inherited controllers and similar.

Thank you! Any help is welcome!

```
public class UserRequest
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserAccountId { get; set; }
    public RequestCode RCode { get; set; }
    public string CodeText { get; set; }
}

public class UserAccount
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]

    public int UserAccountId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Second Name is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3]\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA- 
        Z{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Please confirm your password.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public Role MyRole { get; set; }

    public UserAccount()
    {
        MyRole = Role.Customer;
    }
}

public class Administrator : UserAccount 
{
    public IEnumerable<UserRequest> ReceievedRequests { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : UserAccount
{
    public int Spent { get; set; }
    public ShoppingCart Cart { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<UserRequest> UserRequests { get; set; }
}
```

DataAccessLayer:

```
public class TalonContext : DbContext
{
    public TalonContext() { }

    public TalonContext(DbContextOptions<TalonContext> options) : 
        base(options) { }

    public DbSet<UserAccount> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRequest> Requests { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Administrator>()
            .HasMany(r => r.ReceievedRequests);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
        //    .HasOne(r => r.UserRequests);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()        // <--fixed
            .HasMany(r => r.UserRequests);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRequest>()
            .HasAlternateKey(k => k.UserAccountId);
    }
}
```

Comment: What / where is `SomeModel`?

Comment: It's what it says. You can't use value types (`struct` in C#) as models and have to use reference types instead (`class`es)

Comment: @SLaks It fails for UserRequest .

Comment: @Tseng i do not use struct's . Where did u see that i used structs ?

Comment: In your error message :P You get reference types (classes), value types (structs), enums (which are value types by themselves) and some "non-object" types (interesting read[Not everything derives from object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/). So basically, if its not a reference type it has to be valuetype in 99.99% of all use-casses

Comment: Post your migration file in question and the model related to it

Comment: @Tseng Haha,ok m8. Thanks for help. Im using enum-s (RequestCode) in UserRequest. So, if i understood you, i should not use it, or? What do u suggest, how should i fix it? Thanks for help anyway! :)

Comment: @Tseng It does not generate any migration file.

Comment: Using of enums is allowed, as a field. But not as **collection**. If you need some value in a collection you will have to turn it into an entity (with id and value properties). This can be mapped as collection again (enum, dictionary, set, list). Everything used inside a collection is a relationship (from DB point of view) and for relationships you need primary and foreign keys and these only exists on entities (since value types by their definition are defined by its value, while an entity is defined by its id)

Comment: @Tseng thanks for this explain. I understood it corectly now. Thing which get me to this mistake, is my mistake in Context class. Dont know how this i didnt see. Its problem with definition of relations. I will update code so u can see what is mistake.